# would you answer this short questionnaire to help with university research - revised 

Tags: instruments, drum, cinema, samples

I am currently studying for a BA (Hons) in Music Production.
Part of my assignment requires the creation of sample-based software instruments (namely, Kontakt instruments).

I am creating a cinematic drum package, the key features of which are:

1. Tempo-synched Construction loops
   placed on keys C3 – D3 (the loops
   increase in complexity further up

   the keyboard)
2. Multi-velocity sampling used within
   each loop
3. Modwheel control introduces varying
   degrees of glitched samples
4. Key switching between “Loop” and
   “Kit”. Kit Mode enables MIDI
   compatible drum kit. Create your own
   performances with the clean/glitched
   sounds used in the loops!

**Free Instruments for taking part!**

As part of the research and development element of this assignment, I would appreciate any feedback from composers and sound designers, whether professional or enthusiast.
I will give a free copy of this software to everyone taking part!

1. What would you like to see included with such an instrument?
2. What do you consider fair policy with regards to End-User Licence Agreements?
3. How do you feel about restricted access to included samples within such instruments?     (Many libraries allow you to load preset patches without giving direct access to the included sample content).
4. What time signature ranges would you typically require from such an instrument?
5. If you have any other feedback, please enter it here.

Please note:

Your answers will be used as part of my research.

If you’d prefer to remain anonymous, please state this at the end of the survey.

Thank you for your time,

Elliot 
Thunder.VIP@live.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The ability to manipulate the sound and change envelopes etc

2) Able to use freely in compositions for commercial release.

3) It doesn't bother me at all because I don't think I would need to use the samples in any other package.

4) For me something in the range of 60BPM to 280BPM

5) The quality and sound of the samples is paramount to me and the ability of the sound library to accomodate varying bit resolutions.

http://www.facebook.com/#!/pages/Waylands-Forge-Recording-Studio/129234190490863

Answer (score 1):

1) Intuitive user interface.

2) Licence to permit usage in any music composition (songs, television, film, video games), sound design for all media.

3) Monolith files are quick and easy.

4) Roughly +/- 40% of original tempo

5) Ideally, switchable, as in Stylus RMX. Realistically, 4/4 is fine for most of my work. Since you've included a kit mode I can make manual edits if different time signatures are required.

6) Although almost superfluous to normal working procedures, I find a nice graphical interface is sometimes inspiring. Especially with Kontakt instruments, as they can look quite drab with the standard GUI.

I do not need anonymity. Quite the opposite, in fact.
No free copy necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Drum separation, to use within a drum map or keyboard.

Loops available for user use if buying the patch.

I feel samples should be of use to anyone who uses the product. It seems unfair to supply such a patch to then not be able to use pre made samples.

cinematic drums I would vision as slower more powerful drums. 100bpm to 200bpm